# create fake process in Python

Tags: python, linux

I'm currently working on a stub for tests purpose. Using Python I need to create a process with a specific name ("mysoft") and a specific pid ("1234")

My final purpose is to be able to run the command "pgrep mysoft" on a terminal and get the PID I set (1234).

The process doesn't need to do anything, it just need to exists.

I looked at the subprocess module but I think this is not exactly what I need. What do you think ?

Comment: I don't think it is possible to set a PID to a process. That is the job of the OS & not the user.

Comment: What would happpen if the PID is already in use?

Comment: Ok, i get what you mean, thanks. Let's say I just want to create a process running for a long time with the specific name "mysoft" so that the command "pgrep mysoft" will return a pid. How could I do that?

Comment: OK, *why* do you need `pgrep` to return a specific PID?

Comment: @JulienGreard - name your python script '`myfile`', make it executable and start it with a shebang `#!/usr/bin/python` (not `#!/usr/bin/env python`!). Now when you execute it directly it should show up as `mysoft` in the process table.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To run a process with the name mysoft,

- Create a python with the name mysoft without .py extension.
- Inside that file create a endless while loop or something like that, in a way that it runs long time. Or put a line like `raw_input("enter something")`. It will wait until you give the input.
- Make the file executable by `chmod 775 [filename]`
- First line of this file should be `#!/usr/bin/python`. Change this line according to your python path.
- Put this file system path. Or add this file path to system path. (eg. /home/[user]/bin/)
- Now, type mysoft. It will start.

You need to kill this manually when you want to terminate this process. Setting pid to a process is not possible to my knowledge.

Answer (score 1):

You can't create processes with specific PIDs.  The PID is assigned by the OS.